# Прежде чем опубликовать APK-файл в Google Play, запретите его отладку - ошибка в Google Play

Tags: android, apk

Пытаюсь опубликовать приложение и появляется следующая ошибка при загрузке АПК
"**Прежде чем опубликовать APK-файл в Google Play, запретите его отладку**"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте проверить `Build` -> `Edit Build Types...` -> `Build type` при выводе APK. Возможно у вас в режиме `debug`, a не `release`.

Comment: Да файл дебаг. Там две вкладки релиз и дебаг. А как их переключить. При создании апк я ставил релиз, но все равно создалась версия дебаг

Comment: @BorisRuzanov: [Здесь](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/publish.php) подробно расписано

Comment: Это читал в первую очередь))) Все равно проблема в том, что ставлю релиз, получаю дебаг

Comment: А файл в какой директории должен быть? В app я вижу релиз, он его плей маркет не принимает, в outputs вижу debug

Comment: @BorisRuzanov: Build -> [Select Build Variant](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#changing-variant)